# Scrapy crawler not seeing any items being scraped.

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, scrapy, web-crawler

I am interested to pull out some urls from my database to be crawled first during my next re-crawl.

I have written a custom middleware for this, but due to a bug with JOBDIR, I am unable to achieve what I want using a custom middleware (check the thread [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/scrapy-users/UDJdXRwrQI4))

So I decided to write my own custom Scheduler, since this is where scrapy will be getting all its requests from.

This is my custom queue:

```
class GhostQ(object):
  """
  A Queue of Requests for ghost objects from our last crawl.
  -Can only be popped.
  -Basically a generator with length property
  -Does not include current ghost objects in the scheduler

  A "ghost" object is defined to be an object persisted into our db from crawling that has
  not yet been visited. They exist because we need to persist relationships and the only way
  we can do so is by persisting a blank object first.

  Entities that we have to check:
    -Looks, check if image_url is null
    -Clothing, check if name, brand, type is null
    -Model, check if name is null
  """
  def __init__(self, glooks_cursor, gclothing_cursor, gmodels_cursor, priority=5, yield_per=100):
    self._length = None
    self._generator = None

    self.PRIORITY = priority
    self.YIELD_PER = yield_per

    self.glooks_cursor = glooks_cursor
    self.gclothing_cursor = gclothing_cursor
    self.gmodels_cursor = gmodels_cursor

  def _init_length(self):
    total = self.glooks_cursor.count() + self.gmodels_cursor.count() \
        + self.gclothing_cursor.count()
    self._length = total
    log.msg("GhostQ has %d objects" % self._length)

  def __len__(self):
    if self._length is None:
      self._init_length()
    return self._length

  def _init_generator(self):
    """The use of all here allows us to retrieve everything at once.

    TODO (Somehow this is not breaking??!?)
      -yield_per should be breaking because we are also committing
      -Perhaps we need our our session here?
       i.e new_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=True, bind=engine))
    """
    for look in self.glooks_cursor.yield_per(self.YIELD_PER):
      yield Request(look.url, priority=self.PRIORITY)

    for clothing in self.gclothing_cursor.yield_per(self.YIELD_PER):
      yield Request(clothing.look.url, priority=self.PRIORITY)

    for model in self.gmodels_cursor.yield_per(self.YIELD_PER):
      yield Request(model.url, priority=self.PRIORITY)

  def pop(self):
    if self._generator is None:
      self._generator = self._init_generator()
    try:
      request = self._generator.next()
      if self._length is None:
        self._init_length()
      self._length -= 1
      return request
    except StopIteration:
      return None
```

And this is my custom scheduler:

```
class GiordanoScheduler(Scheduler):
  """Custom scheduler with an additional queue for ghost objects.
  Queries the database for "ghosts" objects and schedules Scrapy to crawl these first.
  """
  def open(self, spider):
    self.ghostq = GhostQ(
        session.query(Look).filter(Look.image_url == None),
        session.query(Clothing).filter(and_(
            Clothing.name == None, Clothing.brand == None, Clothing.type == None)),
        session.query(Model).filter(Model.name == None))
    return Scheduler.open(self, spider)

  def __len__(self):
    if self.dqs:
      return len(self.ghostq) + len(self.dqs) + len(self.mqs)
    else:
      return len(self.ghostq) + len(self.mqs)

  def next_request(self):
    request = self.ghostq.pop()
    if request:
      log.msg("Popping from ghostq: " + request.url, level=log.DEBUG)
      self.stats.inc_value('scheduler/dequeued/ghost', spider=self.spider)
    else:
      request = self.mqs.pop()
      if request:
          log.msg("Popping from mqs: " + request.url, level=log.DEBUG)
          self.stats.inc_value('scheduler/dequeued/memory', spider=self.spider)
      else:
          request = self._dqpop()
          log.msg("Popping from dq: " + request.url, level=log.DEBUG)
          if request:
              self.stats.inc_value('scheduler/dequeued/disk', spider=self.spider)
    if request:
        self.stats.inc_value('scheduler/dequeued', spider=self.spider)
    return request
```

When I run this scheduler, I don't see anything being scraped...

This is the [log](https://gist.github.com/vicngtor/b536f6d10e53ea3b4212)

However, if I disable this line: `request = self.ghostq.pop()`, I see things are being scraped again.

This is a very weird bug. I can't seem to figure out why. I initially suspected the dupefilter being the culprit, but I realized the dupefilter will only filter requests not objects.

This is what it looks like if I disable that line: [log](https://gist.github.com/vicngtor/0ecfb902389fcc06ec93)